# Sorting a Double

Tags: java

I am new to java and am attempting to make a bubble sort work for a double. For some reason sorting is a real hangup for me. Below is the code, but it isn't doing anything. It doesn't error out, but it also doesn't sort. I feel like it is a stupid syntax mistake. My goal is to get the value of an item in my item file to sort descending.

```
public static ArrayList<Item> sortValue(ArrayList<Item> example)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < example.size() - 1; i++ )
            for (int j = 0; j < example.size() - 1 - i; j++)
                if (example.get(j).getValue() == (example.get(j+1).getValue())) {
                    example.add(j+1, example.remove(j));
                }

        return example;
    }
```

I call the method at the beginning of another method:

```
sortValue(example);
```

And still get the below result:

```
books   2.0 2.0 2   2
shoes   1.0 1.0 1   1
sword   10.0    10.0    10  10
```

Not pretty but basically the 10's should be at the top.
Appreciate suggestions!

Comment: Well, your code only does anything if the value at the current index is equal to the value at the immediately adjacent index. And what it does then looks incorrect as well.

Comment: Why are you using `==` to compare? Shouldn't it be `<=` or `>=`? Furthermore, the comparison based on `==` will check if it is the same instance, not necessarily if the objects are semantically equal (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called `BubbleSort`, but you are missing some things:

```
public static ArrayList<Item> sortValue(ArrayList<Item> example) {
    Item aux = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < example.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < example.size() - 1; j++){
            if(example.get(j).getValue() > example.get(j + 1).getValue()){
                aux = example.get(j);
                example.set(j, example.get(j + 1));
                example.set(j + 1, aux);
            }
        }
    }
    return example;
}
```

Notice that we used a local variable called `aux` to store the list `j` position and then update it to the `j + 1` value. Also notice that we are using the `>` (greater than) comparator instead of `==`.

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful, though it does argue with me on lines 7 that j cannot be converted to a double and line 8 that no suitable method for set(int, double)

Comment: and `j` is the position of the array (type `Integer`)... it is not an `double` value... try it with this changes.

Comment: yes!!! thanks! i appreciate the explanation as well and have a better understanding now.